# How to get Apache Virtual Host working on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have Apache installed on an Ubuntu virtual machine.

Typing `http://localhost` in the browser brings up the Apache intro site, so I know Apache works.

I created the file `/home/test/webs/testapp/index.html`:

```
This is a <b>test</b>.
```

I created the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/testapp.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName testapp
 ServerAlias testapp
 DocumentRoot /home/test/webs/testapp
<Directory /home/test/webs/testapp>
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled the virtual host:

```
sudo a2ensite testapp.conf
```

I restarted the Apache server:

```
systemctl reload apache2
```

But when I go to `http://localhost/testapp`, Apache responds:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
>
> Server at localhost Port 80

**What else do I have to do to get my virtual host to work on Ubuntu?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config file you have:

```
ServerName testapp
```

But in your URL you are using:

```
http://localhost/testapp
```

You will need your DNS server to map `testapp` to the IP address of your server. Or, edit your `/etc/hosts` file, adding a line such as:

```
127.0.0.1  testapp
```

Replace 127.0.0.1 with your server's IP address if you are trying to reach it from a different machine.

Then, you can access the host using the url `http://testapp`

**If you want to access the site using `http://localhost/testapp`, you don't need to do any of this**. Instead, you can just use the default virtualhost.

Comment: I added `192.168.30.142 testapp` to my `/etc/hosts` file, and now when I go to `http://testapp` (or `http://testapp/index.html`), it tells me "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this resource."  Where do I provide this permission for the anonymous web user?

Comment: Also, @Bert what do you mean exactly by "use the default virtualhost". When I look for a default virtual host file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, I see only two files: **(1)** `000-default.conf` which I understand is merely a template to make other .conf files, hence the `000-`, and **(2)** `default-ssl.conf` which I understand is only for secure connections and so not relevant in my case.

Comment: Put your web documents in the DocumentRoot in `000-default.conf`, it's a working configuration.

Comment: Yes, I know I can put my web documents under `/var/www/html/testapp` and they will be available at `http://localhost/testapp` but I am trying to set up virtual hosts so that I have can have e.g. numerous users who each have a `public_html` directory under their `home` directory which will be accessible via a separate virtual host, e.g. `/home/user1/public_html` available at `http://192.168.30.142/user1` and `/home/user2/public_html` available at `http://192.168.30.142/user2`, etc.  Your `etc/hosts` tipped helped, but how do I give the web user permission, see above.

Comment: Then you should look into `mod_userdir`, and create a new question if you can't get it working.

Comment: I reasked the question regarding the "Forbidden" error here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1033541/how-to-avoid-the-forbidden-error-when-changing-the-documentroot-in-the-default