# How to avoid the "Forbidden" error when changing the DocumentRoot in the default virtual host file on Ubuntu Apache?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have Apache installed on an Ubuntu virtual machine.

Typing `http://localhost` in the browser brings up the Apache intro site, so I know Apache works.

I created the file `/home/test/webs/testapp/index.html`:

```
This is a <b>test</b>.
```

I changed the **DocumentRoot** in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` so that it points to a directory under my home directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/test/webs
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted the Apache server:

```
systemctl reload apache2
```

But when I go to `http://localhost/testapp`, Apache responds:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

**What do I have to do to give the anonymous web users permission to view this web directory via Apache?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the end of your `000-default.conf` file:

```
<Directory /home/test/webs>
  Options FollowSymLinks 
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After you change the file, reload Apache and you will be able to access the site.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer for Apache 2.2. but for Apache 2.4, I had to change `Allow from all` to `Require all granted`.