# How do I change Apache's DocumentRoot?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I'm using Apache 2.4.41 on Ubuntu 20.04.

With the following configuration, I can successfully view the default Ubuntu Apache page at `/var/www/html/index.html`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # Server Name
        ServerName example1.org
        ServerAlias dev.example2.org

        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

</VirtualHost>
```

If I try to change the `DocumentRoot` directive, however,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # Server Name
        ServerName example1.org
        ServerAlias dev.example2.org

        DocumentRoot "/home/rufus/www/html"

</VirtualHost>
```

then any attempt to view the file `/home/rufus/www/html/index.html` returns a 403 Forbidden error.

Both target directories have the same ownership and permissions all the way to the root directory.  From `ls -lh`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14   root root  /var/
drwxr-xr-x 3    root root  /var/www/
drwxr-xr-x 2    root root  /var/www/html/
-rw-r--r-- 1    root root  /var/www/html/index.html
```

and

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  /home/
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  /home/rufus/
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  /home/rufus/www/
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  /home/rufus/www/html/
-rw-rw-r-- 1  root root  /home/rufus/www/html/index.html
```

I try the same URLs in both cases, http://dev.example2.org and http://dev.example2.org/index.html.  I'm also certain to reload Apache after every config change.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1033541/how-to-avoid-the-forbidden-error-when-changing-the-documentroot-in-the-default) is pretty much identical to mine.  The only answer suggests adding a block like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # Server Name
        ServerName example1.org
        ServerAlias dev.example2.org

        DocumentRoot "/home/rufus/www/html"

        <Directory /home/rufus/www/html>
            Options FollowSymLinks 
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried this with both `Allow from all` and `Require all granted` (as noted in a comment there), reloading Apache after each change.  The second configuration continues to give me a 403 error.

Why does the 2nd one give a 403 Forbidden error, and how do I change my DocumentRoot?

Comment: If you're really hitting dev.example2.com, the virtual host you showed isn't answering that, because it's for dev.example2.org.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Whoops, no, that was a typo when writing the question.  Good catch.  Edited.  I'm attempting to access the correct URL.

Comment: It's best not to set the document root to anywhere in `/home` because the user directories have `700` permissions which is why you are getting the Forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the new directory in the default document root? Should be about line 292.

```
288 # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
 289 # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
 290 # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
 291 #
 292 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
 293
 294 #
 295 # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
 296 # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
 297 # directory (and its subdirectories).
 298 #
 299 # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
 300 # features.
 301 #
 302 <Directory />
 303     Options FollowSymLinks
 304     AllowOverride None
 305 </Directory>
 306
 307 #
 308 # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
 309 # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
 310 # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
 311 # below.
 312 #
 313
 314 #
 315 # This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
 316 #
 317 <Directory "/var/www/html">
```

Comment: This appears to be a very specific config file.  In Ubuntu, the relevant Apache config files are `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and whatever's in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`.  Neither of those files on my system look like what you've posted.  The sample config I gave in the question is in the latter category, and I'm sure that's the appropriate place to set the `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: What I posted was default Apache config from a CentOS install. Run grep -i documentroot /etc/apache2/apache2.conf